# jQuery plugin to "Add Location" similar to Twitter/Facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, google-maps

Is there a jQuery plugin that implements the feature similar to Twitter/Facebook's "Add Location", wherein a user can type in and select a location (with a map preview below).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used it myself, but [geo-autocomplete](http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/) looks to be what you are after. You can see an [example of it here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html). It uses the Google Maps V3 API to do the mapping and the geocoding.

Comment: thanks a lot! this is quite close to what i am looking for, though a more dynamic one (navigate to location on hover) would have been great  :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by navigate to location on hover. Whatever it is I don't think it is something that Facebook supports is it?

Comment: Try this demo of geo-autocomplete. Perhaps it is more like what you mean: http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html

Comment: I mean, as you type in, it provides (autocompletes) options. Now, when you mouse over to one of the options (without selecting one), the map below automatically navigates to that point. Facebook does provide the same experience.

Comment: @Saket see my comment above for a demo that I think is more similar to what you are seeking. Often jQuery plugins are easy to customise to your needs anyway.

Comment: I get a javascript error on visiting the above link. demo4() not defined.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome. It is safe to ignore that error it does not come from the plugin itself, but a call to something that does not exist in the demo.

Comment: Is it possible to **style** this plugin? - change the fonts, etc. in the autocomplete list?

Comment: Yes it can either use jQuery UI themes or custom. Firebug and the plugins documentation will help you in this endeavour.

Comment: Oh, I was asking about the plugin suggested in the answer - http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/

Comment: So was I. It is jQuery UI widget so any of the jQuery UI themes will style it. See http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/